# why this sqoop command throws exception? Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, sqoop

I have a problem with sqoop if you help me I really appreciate your help.

I write a sqoop command from my local computer to export data from hdfs to oracle data database. I use hadoop-3.3.0 and sqoop 1.4.7 in my local computer.

and the error is :

Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster

sqoop command:

```
sqoop export --connect "jdbc:oracle:thin:@(description=(address=(protocol=tcp)(host=172.16.49.30)(port=1521))(connect_data=(service_name=stgdb)))" --table CORE_ETL.DEPOSIT_TURNOVER --username username --password password  --export-dir /tmp/merged_deposit_turnover/sqoop/ --input-fields-terminated-by "," --input-lines-terminated-by '\n'
```

yarn-site.xml:

```
 <configuration>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.acl.enable</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.admin.acl</name>
    <value>*</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
    <value>cluster.com:8032</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.admin.address</name>
    <value>cluster.com:8033</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address</name>
    <value>cluster.com:8030</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address</name>
    <value>cluster.com:8031</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.webapp.address</name>
    <value>cluster.com:8088</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.webapp.https.address</name>
    <value>cluster.com:8090</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.client.thread-count</name>
    <value>50</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.client.thread-count</name>
    <value>50</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.admin.client.thread-count</name>
    <value>1</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb</name>
    <value>1024</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.increment-allocation-mb</name>
    <value>512</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>  yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name>
    <value>2048</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb</name>
    <value>2048</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-vcores</name>
    <value>1</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.increment-allocation-vcores</name>
    <value>1</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-vcores</name>
    <value>2</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.amliveliness-monitor.interval-ms</name>
    <value>1000</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.am.liveness-monitor.expiry-interval-ms</name>
    <value>600000</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.am.max-attempts</name>
    <value>2</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.container.liveness-monitor.interval-ms</name>
    <value>600000</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.nm.liveness-monitor.interval-ms</name>
    <value>1000</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.nm.liveness-monitor.expiry-interval-ms</name>
    <value>600000</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.client.thread-count</name>
    <value>50</value>
  </property>
 <property>
    <name>yarn.application.classpath</name>
    <value>$HADOOP_CONF_DIR,$HADOOP_COMMON_HOME/*,$HADOOP_COMMON_HOME/lib/*,$HADOOP_HDFS_HOME/*,$HADOOP_HDFS_HOME/lib/*,$HADOOP_YARN_HOME/*,$HADOOP_YARN_HOME/lib/*,$HADOOP_COMMON_HOME/share/hadoop/common/*,$HADOOP_COMMON_HOME/share/hadoop/common/lib/*,$HADOOP_HDFS_HOME/share/hadoop/hdfs/*,$HADOOP_HDFS_HOME/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*,$HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*,$HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*,$HADOOP_YARN_HOME/share/hadoop/yarn/*,$HADOOP_YARN_HOME/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*</value>
  </property>
        
    
  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.class</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.fair.FairScheduler</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.resource-calculator</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.resource.DefaultResourceCalculator</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.max-completed-applications</name>
    <value>10000</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.remote-app-log-dir</name>
    <value>/tmp/logs</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.remote-app-log-dir-suffix</name>
    <value>logs</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

environment variables:

```
export HADOOP_HOME=/etc/hadoop
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export YARN_CONF_DIR=/etc/hadoop/etc/hadoop
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/etc/hadoop/etc/hadoop
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
```

hdfs-site.xml

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
    <value>file:///data/dfs/nn</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.servicerpc-address</name>
    <value>cluster.com:8022</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.https.address</name>
    <value>cluster.com:9871</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.https.port</name>
    <value>9871</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.http-address</name>
    <value>cluster.com:9870</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>3</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.blocksize</name>
    <value>67108864</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.client.use.datanode.hostname</name>
    <value>false</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>fs.permissions.umask-mode</name>
    <value>022</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.client.block.write.locateFollowingBlock.retries</name>
    <value>7</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.acls.enabled</name>
    <value>false</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.client.read.shortcircuit</name>
    <value>false</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.domain.socket.path</name>
    <value>/var/run/hdfs-sockets/dn</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.client.read.shortcircuit.skip.checksum</name>
    <value>false</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.client.domain.socket.data.traffic</name>
    <value>false</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.hdfs-blocks-metadata.enabled</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.support.append</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

mapred-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
<value>yarn</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>yarn.app.mapreduce.am.staging-dir</name>
  <value>/user</value>
</property>

    
<property>
  <name>yarn.app.mapreduce.am.env</name>
  <value>HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=/etc/hadoop</value>
</property>
    
<property>
  <name>mapreduce.map.env</name>
  <value>HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=/etc/hadoop</value>
</property>
    
<property>
  <name>mapreduce.reduce.env</name>
  <value>HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=/etc/hadoop</value>
</property>


    <property> 
    <name>mapreduce.application.classpath</name>
    <value>$HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*,$HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*,$HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME/share/hadoop/common/*,$HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME/share/hadoop/common/lib/*,$HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME/share/hadoop/yarn/*,$HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*,$HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME/share/hadoop/hdfs/*,$HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*</value>
</property>
    
</configuration>
```

sqoop error:

```
Warning: /usr/lib/sqoop/../hbase does not exist! HBase imports will fail.
Please set $HBASE_HOME to the root of your HBase installation.
Warning: /usr/lib/sqoop/../hcatalog does not exist! HCatalog jobs will fail.
Please set $HCAT_HOME to the root of your HCatalog installation.
Warning: /usr/lib/sqoop/../accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
Warning: /usr/lib/sqoop/../zookeeper does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ZOOKEEPER_HOME to the root of your Zookeeper installation.
2020-08-22 17:56:24,879 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.7
2020-08-22 17:56:25,173 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
2020-08-22 17:56:25,492 INFO oracle.OraOopManagerFactory: Data Connector for Oracle and Hadoop is disabled.
2020-08-22 17:56:25,579 INFO manager.SqlManager: Using default fetchSize of 1000
2020-08-22 17:56:25,579 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
2020-08-22 17:56:27,694 INFO manager.OracleManager: Time zone has been set to GMT
2020-08-22 17:56:27,883 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM CORE_ETL.DEPOSIT_TURNOVER t WHERE 1=0
2020-08-22 17:56:28,188 INFO orm.CompilationManager: HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME is /etc/hadoop
Note: /tmp/sqoop-hatef/compile/dc629ada72d032251eb72d68f8f68c85/CORE_ETL_DEPOSIT_TURNOVER.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
2020-08-22 17:56:33,829 INFO orm.CompilationManager: Writing jar file: /tmp/sqoop-hatef/compile/dc629ada72d032251eb72d68f8f68c85/CORE_ETL.DEPOSIT_TURNOVER.jar
2020-08-22 17:56:33,902 INFO mapreduce.ExportJobBase: Beginning export of CORE_ETL.DEPOSIT_TURNOVER
2020-08-22 17:56:33,902 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.job.tracker is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.jobtracker.address
2020-08-22 17:56:34,381 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.jar is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.jar
2020-08-22 17:56:36,685 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2020-08-22 17:56:38,545 INFO manager.OracleManager: Time zone has been set to GMT
2020-08-22 17:56:38,638 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.reduce.tasks.speculative.execution is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.reduce.speculative
2020-08-22 17:56:38,645 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.map.tasks.speculative.execution is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.map.speculative
2020-08-22 17:56:38,647 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.map.tasks is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.maps
2020-08-22 17:56:38,996 INFO client.DefaultNoHARMFailoverProxyProvider: Connecting to ResourceManager at hdp-name1-esxi12.sdb247.com/172.16.49.10:8032
2020-08-22 17:56:40,130 INFO mapreduce.JobResourceUploader: Disabling Erasure Coding for path: /user/airflow/.staging/job_1597060731030_0459
2020-08-22 18:01:01,798 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input files to process : 1
2020-08-22 18:01:01,885 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input files to process : 1
2020-08-22 18:01:02,817 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:4
2020-08-22 18:01:02,999 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.map.tasks.speculative.execution is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.map.speculative
2020-08-22 18:01:05,962 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1597060731030_0459
2020-08-22 18:01:05,962 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Executing with tokens: []
2020-08-22 18:01:08,561 INFO conf.Configuration: resource-types.xml not found
2020-08-22 18:01:08,562 INFO resource.ResourceUtils: Unable to find 'resource-types.xml'.
2020-08-22 18:01:08,901 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1597060731030_0459
2020-08-22 18:01:09,086 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://hdp-name1-esxi12.sdb247.com:8088/proxy/application_1597060731030_0459/
2020-08-22 18:01:09,088 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1597060731030_0459
2020-08-22 18:01:11,442 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1597060731030_0459 running in uber mode : false
2020-08-22 18:01:11,444 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
2020-08-22 18:01:11,671 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1597060731030_0459 failed with state FAILED due to: Application application_1597060731030_0459 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1597060731030_0459_000002 exited with  exitCode: 1
Failing this attempt.Diagnostics: [2020-08-22 18:03:19.337]Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1597060731030_0459_02_000001
Exit code: 1

[2020-08-22 18:03:19.338]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1. Error file: prelaunch.err.
Last 4096 bytes of prelaunch.err :
Last 4096 bytes of stderr :
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster

Please check whether your etc/hadoop/mapred-site.xml contains the below configuration:
<property>
  <name>yarn.app.mapreduce.am.env</name>
  <value>HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=${full path of your hadoop distribution directory}</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>mapreduce.map.env</name>
  <value>HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=${full path of your hadoop distribution directory}</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>mapreduce.reduce.env</name>
  <value>HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=${full path of your hadoop distribution directory}</value>
</property>

[2020-08-22 18:03:19.339]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1. Error file: prelaunch.err.
Last 4096 bytes of prelaunch.err :
Last 4096 bytes of stderr :
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster

Please check whether your etc/hadoop/mapred-site.xml contains the below configuration:
<property>
  <name>yarn.app.mapreduce.am.env</name>
  <value>HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=${full path of your hadoop distribution directory}</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>mapreduce.map.env</name>
  <value>HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=${full path of your hadoop distribution directory}</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>mapreduce.reduce.env</name>
  <value>HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=${full path of your hadoop distribution directory}</value>
</property>

For more detailed output, check the application tracking page: http://cluster.com:8088/cluster/app/application_1597060731030_0459 Then click on links to logs of each attempt.
. Failing the application.
2020-08-22 18:01:11,780 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 0
2020-08-22 18:01:11,916 WARN mapreduce.Counters: Group FileSystemCounters is deprecated. Use org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.FileSystemCounter instead
2020-08-22 18:01:11,921 INFO mapreduce.ExportJobBase: Transferred 0 bytes in 273.1812 seconds (0 bytes/sec)
2020-08-22 18:01:12,013 WARN mapreduce.Counters: Group org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task$Counter is deprecated. Use org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskCounter instead
2020-08-22 18:01:12,015 INFO mapreduce.ExportJobBase: Exported 0 records.
2020-08-22 18:01:12,015 ERROR mapreduce.ExportJobBase: Export job failed!
2020-08-22 18:01:12,016 ERROR tool.ExportTool: Error during export: 
Export job failed!
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ExportJobBase.runExport(ExportJobBase.java:445)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.OracleManager.exportTable(OracleManager.java:465)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ExportTool.exportTable(ExportTool.java:80)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ExportTool.run(ExportTool.java:99)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:147)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:183)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:234)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:243)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:252)
```

Comment: `For more detailed output, check the application tracking page `

Comment: etc/hadoop is the config directory, not the mapreduce classpath, also confused about `/etc/hadoop/etc/hadoop`

Comment: And I'm not sure Sqoop yet supports hadoop 3

Comment: thank you . for hadoop 2.7 I also had similar problem

Comment: Have you tried using Ambari, for example, to properly install Hadoop and Scoop?

Comment: No! I wanted to install Sqoop locally and use that to transfer data from HDFS to Oracle. but Hadoop cluster installed via Cloudera

Comment: Cloudera comes with Sqoop as well

Comment: I can run Spark app on this Hadoop cluster but when I want to run mapreduce job like "yarn jar $YARN_EXAMPLES/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-3.3.0.jar pi 2 2" this error "Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster" happens again!

Comment: Right... Because, as the error says, the 3 `.env` properties in the mapred-site are incorrectly referencing the necessary paths where you've installed Hadoop

Comment: thank you for spending your time with this, I have a question, these variables should point to necessary jars in my local machine or where they are installed in Hadoop nodes?

Comment: On the nodes. Ideally each node would have the files in the same location, so therefore copying the same `mapred-site.xml` file between each server would work. You'd also ideally get one node working in "pseudo-distributed" mode first before expanding the cluster (if not using Cloudera Manager or Ambari)

Comment: thank you very much @OneCricketeer I'll check this

Comment: @OneCricketeer you were right, I copy the mapred-site.xml file from cloudera gateway node to my local machine and it worked! if you mind you can post your answer and I will accept that. thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention you have a cluster installed with Cloudera, but it is not clear where Sqoop is running or where you got those XML files.

If you have a fully installed Cloudera Cluster, Sqoop should already be installed and configured there for you to run without much issues (you might need extra JDBC drivers, but that should be it)

Otherwise, if you are trying to setup Sqoop (and Hadoop) externally, you'll want to grab a copy of the `$HADOOP_HOME/conf` folder from a worker node in the Hadoop cluster to make sure all the client configurations are the same.

Comment: I wanted to run Sqoop from my local computer.